# Merge code files with nuget instead of overwrite

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I have built several nuget packages that can be used either individually or together. Each has a specific file called Config.cs.pp which then of course becomes Config.cs when you add the package. The problem is, if I am using multiple packages, instead of merging the files, I am prompted to ignore or overwrite Config.cs with each package I add. I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to force nuget to merge instead (or keep both with ~1 maybe)?

I'm guessing it is just a limitation of nuget. But figured I'd ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. You would need to name your files so they are different or put them in a different directory.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.